# Idiomatic Python for generating a new object from within a class

Tags: python

I have a method on one of my objects that returns a new instance of that same class. I'm trying to figure out the most idiomatic way to write this method such that it generates a new object of the same type without duplicating code.

Since this method uses data from the instance, my first pass is:

```
class Foo(object):
    def get_new(self):
        data = # Do interesting things
        return Foo(data)
```

However, if I subclass Foo and don't override get_new, calling get_new on SubFoo would return a Foo! So, I could write a classmethod:

```
class Foo(object):

    @classmethod
    def get_new(cls, obj):
        data = # Munge about in objects internals
        return cls(data)
```

However, the data I'm accessing is specific to the object, so it seems to break encapsulation for this not to be a "normal" (undecorated) method. Additionally, you then have to call it like `SubFoo.get_new(sub_foo_inst)`, which seems redundant. I'd like the object to just "know" which type to return -- the same type as itself!

I suppose it's also possible to add a factory method to the class, and override the return type everywhere, without duplicating the logic, but that seems to put a lot of work on the subclasses.

So, my question is, what's the best way to write a method that gives flexibility in type of class without having to annotate the type all over the place?

Comment: classmethods themselves aren't very idiomatic on Python; factories can just be plain functions that live in the same module as the class.

Comment: @Adam: Class methods have their uses (e.g. when you're using class variables and don't want to break inheritance). Static methods are much worse.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to make it more flexible for subclassing, you can simply use the [`self.__class__`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__) special attribute:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def get_new(self):
        data = # Do interesting things
        return self.__class__(data)
```

Note that using the `@classmethod` approach will prevent you from accessing data within any one instance, removing it as a viable solution in instances where `#Do interesting things` relies on data stored within an instance.

For Python 2, I do not recommend using `type(self)`, as this will return an inappropriate value for [classic classes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) (i.e., those not subclassed from the base `object`):

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> type(f)
<type 'instance'>
>>> f.__class__    # Note that the __class__ attribute still works
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

For Python 3, this is not as much of an issue, as all classes are derived from `object`, however, I believe `self.__class__` is considered the more Pythonic idiom.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. 

This is only week 2 or so of seriously using Python, so I'm still not totally aware of all the pieces and how they get used.

Comment: Using `type(self)`, as möter suggests, does essentially the same thing but is slightly cleaner IMHO. But maybe that's just my aversion for anything with four underscores.

Comment: @Thomas: I actually do not recommend using `type()`, and I have added an explanation of why to my answer.

Comment: I agree with @Thomas. In a time where Python 2 is dead, `type(...)` seems in fact cleaner. Dunder methods should never directly be accessed (or it's usually not regarded as Pythonic), or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the builtin 'type'.

```
type(instance)
```

is that instance's class.